# How to make <select> element not to choose first option as selected by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [jquery interdependencies library](https://github.com/miohtama/jquery-interdependencies) for building complex form (when you show fields depend on values from other fields).

So, I have `<select>` element

```
<select placeholder="Select Product ID Type" id="form_product_id_type" name="form_product_id_type">
    <option label="01 - Proprietary" value="01">01 - Proprietary</option>
    <option label="02 - ISBN-10" value="02">02 - ISBN-10</option>
    <option label="03 - GTIN-13" value="03">03 - GTIN-13</option>
    <option label="04 - UPC" value="04">04 - UPC</option>
    <option label="05 - ISMN-10" value="05">05 - ISMN-10</option>
    ...
</select>
```

If user selects option "01" then I should show another field "TypeDescription" where user can describe his proprietary id scheme. If user selects any other options from select -"TypeDescription" field will not appear.

The thing is that first option

```
<option label="01 - Proprietary" value="01">01 - Proprietary</option>
```

is always selected by default when you open a page and therefore field "TypeDescription" is shown always.

Are there any ways to unselect all options from `<select>` element? My goal is when user open page he should not see field "TypeDescription".

Attached [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TbadA/1/)

Comment: Couldn't you just put an empty option first `<option></option>`?

Comment: Give this a try: `$("#form_product_id_type").prop("selectedIndex", -1);`  http://jsfiddle.net/TbadA/3/

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes, it looks like this code does what I need. But since problem can be solved with pure html I would prefer this way. Anyway, thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way to do that is to add an empty option.

```
<select placeholder="Select Product ID Type" id="form_product_id_type" name="form_product_id_type">
    <option selected value="">Select Product ID Type</option>
    <option label="01 - Proprietary" value="01">01 - Proprietary</option>
    <option label="02 - ISBN-10" value="02">02 - ISBN-10</option>
    <option label="03 - GTIN-13" value="03">03 - GTIN-13</option>
    <option label="04 - UPC" value="04">04 - UPC</option>
    <option label="05 - ISMN-10" value="05">05 - ISMN-10</option>
    ...
</select>
```

A `<select>` always has something selected; if the user hasn't interacted with the control, and none of the `<option>` elements have the "selected" attribute, then the first one is selected.

I'm pretty sure that "placeholder" does nothing on `<select>` elements.

Answer (score 3):

Add an option at the top that doesn't have a value. The `placeholder` attribute doesn't work for select boxes.

```
<select id="form_product_id_type" name="form_product_id_type">
    <option value="">Select Product ID</option>
    <option label="01 - Proprietary" value="01">01 - Proprietary</option>
    <option label="02 - ISBN-10" value="02">02 - ISBN-10</option>
    <option label="03 - GTIN-13" value="03">03 - GTIN-13</option>
    <option label="04 - UPC" value="04">04 - UPC</option>
    <option label="05 - ISMN-10" value="05">05 - ISMN-10</option>
    ...
</select>
```