# jquery :selected always picks first element if none are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, selected

I have a select element

```
<select id='bill_to'>
     <option value='a634jhj2'>test@c.com</option>
     <option value='agfd4ghj2'>test2@c.com</option>
     <option value='asdf634jhj2'>tes3@c.com</option>
     <option value='agf2342d4ghj2'>test4@c.com</option>
</select>
```

If I do

```
  $('#bill_to').find(':selected')
```

it returns the first option even though it is not selected.

If an option is selected

```
  $('#bill_to').find(':selected')
```

works as expected and returns the correct option

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug. This is driving me crazy.
I just want it to return [] if there is nothing selected

Comment: By default the first option in the select element will be selected. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332437/how-to-make-select-element-not-to-choose-first-option-as-selected-by-default) This would help you.

Comment: why not use $('#bill_to').text() instead?

Comment: You may add a default value like this `<option value='0'><option>` and check if selected option value !== 0  or !== false

Comment: @Saechel  The output of `$('#bill_to').text()` would be `""`

Comment: You should fix that HTML. `</option>`

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy yes but i believe its better than using selected for it will always give the first option as the result when he wanted it to be empty when nothings selected. by the way rGraham is right terminate those option tags properly.

Comment: but there is never not a value selected, that's what he's trying to say. There is always a selected value when the page renders, and it will be the first value unless any other is specified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are no select option with `selected` attribute, first option will be the selected option by default. You can try adding another option to top that contains default value as follow.

```
<select id='bill_to'>
     <option value='-1'>Select<option>
     <option value='a634jhj2'>test@c.com<option>
     <option value='agfd4ghj2'>test2@c.com<option>
     <option value='asdf634jhj2'>tes3@c.com<option>
     <option value='agf2342d4ghj2'>test4@c.com<option>
</select>
```

If nothing is selected you will get `-1` and then you can proceed.

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/fZv5t/

Comment: Is there really no other way? I'm using this select in a widget and this would be very inconvenient way of handling it

Comment: Sorry, It is the default behavior of `Select`, you have to handle it this way.

Answer (score 2):

I have add closing tag of option "", without this I am having an empty option get inserted after each option in the dropdown. Issue can be seen in this [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/MfsFD/)

And the working example is on this [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/xFz3q/)

Try to add an empty option tag:

```
<select id='bill_to'>
    <option></option>
    <option value='a634jhj2'>test@c.com</option>
    <option value='agfd4ghj2'>test2@c.com</option>
    <option value='asdf634jhj2'>tes3@c.com</option>
    <option value='agf2342d4ghj2'>test4@c.com</option>
</select>
```

Here you will get empty string, like this:

```
$('#bill_to').find(':selected').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't or don't want to add a dummy first `<option>`, as an alternative you can grab and test the selected attribute of the element returned by `:selected`, for example:

```
var selection = $('#bill_to').find(':selected');
var really = (selection.attr('selected') != null);
var selval = really ? selection.val() : "";      /* or null or whatever */
```