# How to prevent select of new option added to select element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm adding new options to select tag and I don't want any of them to be selected.  I've tried a couple of ways to do it but every time first option is selected. Here's code:

```js
const $selectField = $('.clsname');
const array = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'];
$selectField.empty();
array.forEach(function(iter, elem) {
  $selectField.append(new Option(iter, elem, false, false));
});
$selectField.show();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select hidden class="clsname"></select>
```

As far as I understand using `new Option()` with `defaultSelected` and selected set to `false` should resolve the problem.

Additionally, I've tried adding something like this after `forEach`, but it doesn't work either.

```
$selectField.children("option:selected").prop("selected", false);
```

Comment: Is this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033922/how-to-show-disable-html-select-option-in-by-default?

Comment: If you do not want them to be selected then what are the uses of adding them?

Comment: @AndrewHalpern unfortunately not

Comment: @Mamun I want user to select them and non of the options should be selected before he decides which one to choose

Comment: What about this? Setting an empty first open? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332437/how-to-make-select-element-not-to-choose-first-option-as-selected-by-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of the select field to `null` after you added your options.

```
$('#mySelect').val(null)
```

```js
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
 $option = $('<option></option>').text('Option ' + i).val(i);
 $('select').append($option);
}
$('select').val(null)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>


</select>
```